# How to calculate the fb likes in admin panel using php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating one admin site with login system using php. In that I need to calculate the number of likes in facebook for ("www.facebook.com/tarehub") this page in my dashboard... Could anyone help me to do this???

I'm creating fb-like button in end-user site like,

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/tarehub" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
               </div>
```

Thanks in advance,

Sanjita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code for fb like count

```
$ch = curl_init("http://graph.facebook.com/tarehub");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($raw);
echo $data->likes . " likes";
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, try this (replace http://www.google.com to your URL)

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.google.com

or using FQL (!deprecated!)

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://www.google.com%22